# NSNull length crash with textField,

Tags: ios, textfield, nsnull

when i enter any character or number with keyboard.the app crash with this info

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x103b5daf0'".

And every textfield that used in the app  has this problem.The textfield is in a storybord-based appliction.[this is the textfield delegate i overwrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFF9G.png) and [this is the exception throw call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFX89.png)

Comment: First of all, if you check a string use `isEqualToString:` , then just check if it is `nil` or if `textField.text.length == 0`

Comment: Did you implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string` delegate?

Comment: Please paste source code instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you somewhere set the textField's text property to `NSNull` (which is a bug).

It's not (like other answers state) the comparison `[textField.text isEqual:[NSNull null]]` that leads to the bug. This line is nonsense, but can't result in the crash.

Search for places where you set the textfield's `text` property and check that the value is always of type `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

replace `([textField.text isEqual:[NSNull null]])` with `(textField.text.length == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your `exception throw call stack`, this crash is caused of by this method [textfield.text isEqual:[NSNull null]]`. You can use this code:

```
if (textfield.text){

}
```

Or

```
if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:@"your text"]){

}
```

`textfield.text` is an object which class is `NSString` and [NSNull null] is also an object that represent empty object.